# How do I get opam package manager to print emoji on Linux?

Tags: emoji, opam

When I run a command like `opam update` on my Mac, the program prints little camel emojis next to the name of each step:

```
=-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org
```

[image: Updating package repositories with camel emoji]

How do I get this to show up when I ssh into a Linux server? I understand that emoji support is inconsistent across Linux graphical environments, but feel like they should be printed over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

use `export OPAMUTF8MSGS=1`, as documented in [opam --help](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/2.0/man/opam.html#lbAI). For the reason you mentionned — inconsistent support across Linuxes — this is turned on by default on OSX only.